# How to use Boost MST Algorithm on a complete Graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I am very new to the BGL. I have the following problem: I've got a very large complete Graph and weights for every edge and need to evaluate a Minimum Spanning Tree.
I would like to use the Boost Graph Libraries implementation. What structures should I use to represent my complete graph and how would I call the Algorithm? Also I'd like to store the resulting subgraph in some graph structure so that I can perform different operations on the MST afterwards.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You will need to read the documentation. Here's one place to start https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/graph/doc/quick_tour.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [simple example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e521a840a56e0ba8). I'd suggest an adjacency matrix since the graph is going to be complete, so the matrix is very dense.

```
using Graph =
    boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property,
                            boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;
```

Now let's create a graph

```
int main() {
    Graph g(23);
```

Picking an arbitrary number (23) of vertices for this example. Let's use randomly generated weights:

```
auto  weight_distribution = std::bind(
        std::lognormal_distribution<>{0, 0.25},
        std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
```

Creating all the edges to make the graph complete:

```
for (Vertex v = 0; v < num_vertices(g); ++v)
    for (Vertex u = v + 1; u < num_vertices(g); ++u)
        add_edge(v, u, 100*weight_distribution(), g);
```

Now, let's use Prim's algorithm (since all the weights are non-negative):

```
std::vector<Vertex> parent(num_vertices(g));
prim_minimum_spanning_tree(g, parent.data());
```

This writes the predecessor for each vertex in the `parent` vector (which is called the *predecessor map*).

### Adding Some Output

For more interesting results, let's add some checks and output:

```
assert(std::ranges::all_of(
    make_iterator_range(edges(g)),
    [ew = get(boost::edge_weight, g)](auto e) { return ew[e] > 0; }));
```

Making sure the data satisfies the weight pre-condition. You might also do a completeness check depending on how you get your input data.

```
std::vector<Vertex> parent(num_vertices(g));
std::map<Vertex, double> distance;
auto root = vertex(0, g); // or just 0
```

Let's pass the optional arguments `distance_map` and `root_vertex`:

```
prim_minimum_spanning_tree(g, parent.data(),
       boost::root_vertex(root)
       .distance_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(distance)));
```

That uses named parameters (starting with `boost::root_vertex` and chaining with `.other_parameter(...).even_more(...)`. You can of course start with any named parameter).

Now we can use the recorded data:

```
double total_path_weight = 9;

for (Vertex v = 0; v < num_vertices(g); ++v) {
    auto p      = parent[v];
    auto weight = distance[v];

    std::cout << p << " -> " << v << " weight " << weight
              << (p == v ? " ROOT" : "") << "\n";

    total_path_weight += weight;
}

std::cout << "Total path weight " << total_path_weight << "\n";
```

### DEMO

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82aba581800bb46f)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.hpp>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using Graph =
    boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property,
                            boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;

using boost::make_iterator_range;

int main() {
    Graph g(23);
    auto  weight_distribution = std::bind(std::lognormal_distribution<>{0, 0.25},
                                         std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});

    for (Vertex v = 0; v < num_vertices(g); ++v)
        for (Vertex u = v + 1; u < num_vertices(g); ++u)
            add_edge(v, u, 100*weight_distribution(), g);

    assert(std::ranges::all_of(
        make_iterator_range(edges(g)),
        [ew = get(boost::edge_weight, g)](auto e) { return ew[e] > 0; }));

    std::vector<Vertex> parent(num_vertices(g));
    std::map<Vertex, double> distance;
    auto root = vertex(0, g); // or just 0

    prim_minimum_spanning_tree(g, parent.data(),
           boost::root_vertex(root)
           .distance_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(distance)));

    double total_path_weight = 9;

    for (Vertex v = 0; v < num_vertices(g); ++v) {
        auto p      = parent[v];
        auto weight = distance[v];

        std::cout << p << " -> " << v << " weight " << weight
                  << (p == v ? " ROOT" : "") << "\n";

        total_path_weight += weight;
    }

    std::cout << "Total path weight " << total_path_weight << "\n";
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
0 -> 0 weight 0 ROOT
15 -> 1 weight 64.6241
21 -> 2 weight 62.1609
1 -> 3 weight 69.207
5 -> 4 weight 71.9255
2 -> 5 weight 68.3983
14 -> 6 weight 66.6639
17 -> 7 weight 69.5045
20 -> 8 weight 78.9941
6 -> 9 weight 69.3287
4 -> 10 weight 62.7512
0 -> 11 weight 65.9305
15 -> 12 weight 70.2627
4 -> 13 weight 67.9708
22 -> 14 weight 73.3816
14 -> 15 weight 61.069
6 -> 16 weight 63.5795
5 -> 17 weight 66.0981
6 -> 18 weight 54.6061
14 -> 19 weight 73.9725
5 -> 20 weight 74.7002
0 -> 21 weight 71.8757
17 -> 22 weight 68.6378
Total path weight 1504.64
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Something like this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I have a question though, is there any way to achieve this more efficiently? I seems to me, that the add_edge function consumes a lot of time. I am currently running this on a complete graph with 40k vertices and it takes me a long time to add all those edges. If I store my weights in a vector, my code runs much faster. Could I use this instead to initialize the graph?

Comment: Sure. Everything in BGL is generic. Just pass the property map for the vector instead of the edge weights. If you share some more code (that would have been something to include in the question in the first place) we could (have) help(ed)